# How to test background audio in iOS UI Tests

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, ui-testing

I want to test various aspects of background music and speech in iOS UI Testing;

- is background music playing?
- did music change on new scene?
- does music mute on interruptions from phone call, FaceTime etc?
- is speech uttered when required ?

Can't seem to find any api documentation or tutorials that show how to do these types of tests.

Have tried the following code in my UI test class just to test if music is playing. The code attempts to either detect audioSession state (`audioSession.isOtherAudioPlaying`) or events related to playback (`AVAudioSessionInterruption`). Neither approach is detecting the music.

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    continueAfterFailure = false
    XCUIApplication().launch()

    app = XCUIApplication();
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.handleInterruption(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVAudioSessionInterruption, object: nil)

}

@objc func handleInterruption(_ notification: Notification) {

    print("Received audio interrupt", notification);

}

override func tearDown() {
    super.tearDown()
}


func testIsBackgroundMusicPlaying() {
    let audioSession: AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance();

    if (audioSession.isOtherAudioPlaying) {
        print ("Other audio is playing");
    }


}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "New scene" is your code - mocking should cover this. "is speech uttered when required" should be covered by becoming `AVSpeechSynthesizer`'s delegate and checking that your receive the expected callbacks. that is if you trust that `AVFoundation` is not lying to you... Music _does_ mute on phone call type interruptions... but the rest of this stuff is very hard to test on the device and impossible on the simulator. You could set up a test device observed via a camera that checks your assertions, but it's a lot of work and in the end... why bother?